# Wire two USB devices to one PC port

Tags: usb

I have an old hub that sucks, so I converted it to a USB-tripler by soldering all of the input 4 wires to the corresponding wires on the output connectors. I had to do this because modern devices require 2.0 or 2.8 volts on d+, and refuse to charge if d+ is shortened or not connected. It works well charging three devices from a 1a wall adapter.
But if someone accidentally connects this to a PC port, what will happen? Well if there is only one device, it would be detected no problem. But if two devices are wired to the same port, how dangerous is that?
I would prefer the first connected device to be identified in the system, while the second connected devices just get the power.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first steps in USB enumeration is to send a reset signal by driving D+ and D- low.  All the devices plugged in will see the reset and think it was intended for them.  After the reset they will each think they have address 0 and respond to requests to that address.  The result will be multiple devices trying to drive the bus at the same time, for a brief period before the host gives up.

I think it wouldn't damage anything, but you will be causing a short circuit for a few microseconds which is bad.